# gcc -S not working?

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++

I am trying to have a look at assembly code generated by g++. The normal way is `-S`. As I also want the corresponding source code, I am adding a `-fverbose-asm`. (I tried both with and without.)

I expect a `.s` file to be generated, but none is.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -S -fverbose-asm -DNAMESPACE -I/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/include -O2 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib,--hash-style=gnu -mthumb-interwork -mno-thumb -isystem/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/include -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fomit-frame-pointer -fpermissive -fPIC  -mfpu=neon -MMD -MP -MF"Src/Kernel Filters SSEI.d" -MT"Src/Kernel\ Filters\ SSEI.d" -o "Src/Kernel Filters SSEI.o" "../Src/Kernel Filters SSEI.cpp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assembly output is the file `Src/Kernel Filters SSEI.o`

Another issue is that `-MT` seems used incorrectly, it causes the target of the generated dependency to be the dependency file itself, rather than the object file.

Comment: Works now, thanks. The "verbose" comments are somewhat disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any `-o` option to GCC to get the `.s` file. You are correct in passing `-fverbose-asm -S` to it. You may want some optimization, e.g. `-O1`

<sup>I suspect that your `Src/Kernel Filters SSEI.o` file may contain assembly code. I also strongly recommend avoiding spaces in your source or object file name. Name it `Kernel_Filters_SSEI.cpp`</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I improved my answer by a suspicion.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is fine as well.